# passing 2d array with variable boundaries to a function

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I have an `array` who's boundaries are defined by another variable (not a constant):

```
 int max = 10;
 int array[max][max];
```

Now I have a function which uses that `array`, but I have no idea on how to pass the array to the function. How do I do this?

So to make it more clear, how do I make this work (I thought about using classes, but the variable `max` is defined by user-input so I can't make the array a member of the class because `max` would have to be a constant)

```
void function (int array[max][max])
{
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `max` has to be a constant as it is.

Comment: c++, Use stl types like `std::vector`. in c++ you cannot define variable length arrays.

Comment: Are you asking if there is a way to pass a VLA in C++ ? the answer is *yes*. Its called "use a `std::vector<>` and pass it by reference."

Comment: listen to the `vector` advice, passing 2d arrays to functions gets messy fast..

Comment: So there is no way to pass the array without using constants? I know that it's possible with vectors, but I'm trying to do it with an array..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>    
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int** Matrix;                     //A pointer to pointers to an int.
    int rows,columns;
    cout << "Enter number of rows: ";
    cin >> rows;
    cout << "Enter number of columns: ";
    cin >> columns;
    Matrix = new int*[rows];         //Matrix is now a pointer to an array of 'rows' pointers.

    for(int i=0; i<rows; i++) {
        Matrix[i] = new int[columns];    //the i place in the array is initialized
        for(int j = 0;j<columns;j++) {   //the [i][j] element is defined
                cout<<"Enter element in row "<<(i+1)<<" and column "<<(j+1)<<": ";
            cin>>Matrix[i][j];
        }
    }
    cout << "The matrix you have input is:\n";

    for(int i=0; i < rows; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j < columns; j++)
            cout << Matrix[i][j] << "\t";   //tab between each element
        cout << "\n";               //new row
    }
    for(int i=0; i<rows; i++)                
        delete[] Matrix[i];         //free up the memory used
}
```

Comment: This should help you create it by user defined sizes. Then take the array/matrix and pass it through the array void `function(int *array)`

Comment: Thanks! I think I got it now.

Answer (score 0):

If the array size stays constant in the function, you might consider using a pointer plus a second parameter for the array size.

```
void function(int *array, const int size)
{
}
```

If you want to change the size in the function, you might really consider a std implementation like std::vector.